# Possible to insert missing function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, greasemonkey

When I do the below in Firefox/GreaseMonkey, then I get

```
TypeError: $.bmenu is not a function
```

so I am gussing the `hide()` operation somehow messes the sites JS up.

Would it be possible to insert a dummy `$.bmenu` function to satisfy the site code, so my script can continue?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        example.com
// @namespace   https://example/
// @description https://example.com/
// @include     https://example.com/*
// @include     http://example.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
// @require     https://greasyfork.org/scripts/5392-waitforkeyelements/code/WaitForKeyElements.js?version=115012
// ==/UserScript==

waitForKeyElements('#bmenu', removeBmenu);

function removeBmenu(jNode) {
  jNode.hide();
}

is_left_menu();
```

**Update**

This is the code that I ideally would like to just disable, so it is never run.

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $.bmenu();
    $('#triggerPopup').trigger('click');
  });
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#bmenu-container, .close").click(function () {
       window.open("https://example.com/").blur();
       window.focus();
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: `$.bmenu=function(){}` is not a clean way to solve your problem, maybe you could provide more informations about the error...

Comment: @n00dl3 Good point. I have updated OP with the code in question.